# What permission have Visual Studio Extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

What permission have Visual Studio Extensions?
Do they have file access and can send data to internet?

How can it be that i cant find informations about that?

Comment: Your extensions are just that- extensions. They have whatever access your program has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sand boxing for VS extensions so they have the same permissions as VS process, including admin access when VS is running elevated.

Comment: that is really frightening. How can that be?

Comment: Uninstalling right away